# Error in procedure

Tags: mysql, procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `SearchUserX`( IN columnName VARCHAR( 28 ) , IN search INT )
BEGIN
       DECLARE finished INT DEFAULT FALSE ;
       DECLARE tableName VARCHAR ( 28 ) ;
       DECLARE stmtFields TEXT ;

    DECLARE tableNames CURSOR FOR
              SELECT DISTINCT`TABLE_NAME` FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
              WHERE `COLUMN_NAME` = columnName AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'comments' ORDER BY `ORDINAL_POSITION` ;
       DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = TRUE;
       SET stmtFields = '' ;
       OPEN tableNames;
       readTables: LOOP
              FETCH tableNames INTO tableName ;
              IF finished THEN
                     LEAVE readTables ;
              END IF;
              SET stmtFields = CONCAT(
                     stmtFields , IF ( LENGTH( stmtFields ) > 0 , ' AND' , ''  ) ,
                     ' `', tableName ,'`.`' , columnName , '`= ' , search ,'') ;
       END LOOP;
       SET @stmtQuery=CONCAT('SELECT * FROM `' , tableName , '` WHERE ' , stmtFields ) ;
       PREPARE stmt FROM @stmtQuery ;
       EXECUTE stmt ;
       CLOSE tableNames ;
END
```

I have error can somebody help me:

```
0   11:42:47    call SearchUserX('UserId',2)    Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'TabExample.UserId' in 'where clause'
```

or I have a problem with syntax in clausure `stmtFields`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the `{}` toolbar button. I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 0):

as error says:

> Unknown column 'TabExample.UserId' in 'where clause'

You need to add column `UserId` in your table `TabExample`.

Comment: but I have a column UserId. I think its a problem with stmtFields

Comment: try this and past output query here. call SearchUserX('UserId',2); select @stmtQuery;

Comment: 'SELECT * FROM `Newsweek1` WHERE  `TabExample`.`UserId`= 2 AND `Newsweek1`.`UserId`= 2'

But TabExample dont have a value only have a column UserId.

Comment: you see the query is wrongly formed. the table used in from and where is different.

Comment: instead of fetching multiple tables through cursor you need to pass table name in argument and don't forget to mark UP and accept answer.

Comment: but I must searching in all tables in database and search UserId = 2 or other value. If I pass table_name in argument I always get one table which I writing

Comment: the you need to write select query inside loop or for multiple tables you need to join them dynamically.

Comment: like this ? 
http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/70/posts/10883/search-a-value-in-character-column-of-all-tables.aspx

but how rewrite query to mysql I have a problem like '